# Profile fields export/import

Tags: users

I have many user profile fields created at admin/config/people/accounts/fields in my drupal 7 local (offline) site. I would like to transfer all fields configuration to my online drupal site.
Is there any way to do this like views export/import feature? I don't want to re-create all fields in my online site.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [Features](http://drupal.org/project/features) module can export content types, fields, views and allow you to import into another Drupal site.

> The features module enables the capture and management of features in Drupal. A feature is a collection of Drupal entities which taken together satisfy a certain use-case.
>
> Features provides a UI and API for taking different site building components from modules with exportables and bundling them together in a single feature module. A feature module is like any other Drupal module except that it declares its components (e.g. views, contexts, CCK fields, etc.) in its .info file so that it can be checked, updated, or reverted programmatically.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Nice module. Just one thing is that I got to uninstall the exported feature module so that it is not listed in the module list.

Answer (score 3):

One option could be the [Bundle Copy](http://drupal.org/project/bundle_copy) module that lets you export and import the whole user entity.

Another option would be the [Field Tools](https://www.drupal.org/project/field_tools) module that provides export/import functionalities specific for fields.